# socket.getaddrinfo returns weird results as IPv6 addresses

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, dns, ipv6

While helping someone debug a piece of code, I noticed that on their computer, this code:

```
python -c "import socket; print(socket.getaddrinfo('dickson.freenode.net', None))"
```

returns this:

> [(2, 1, 6, '', ('208.80.155.68', 0)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('208.80.155.68', 0)), (2, 3, 0, '', ('208.80.155.68', 0)), (10, 1, 6, '', (10, '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00& \x00\x00\x08a\x02\x02')), (10, 2, 17, '', (10, '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00& \x00\x00\x08a\x02\x02')), (10, 3, 0, '', (10, '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00& \x00\x00\x08a\x02\x02'))]

I find the last results particularily strange: the last item of each of the tuples should be a pair `(ipaddress, port)`, but in that case, some are `(10, '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00& \x00\x00\x08a\x02\x02')`

Is that an expected behavior of Python, or a bug?
In both case, what does this '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00& \x00\x00\x08a\x02\x02' mean?

On one of my computer, the result is this:

> [(2, 1, 6, '', ('208.80.155.68', 0)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('208.80.155.68', 0)), (2, 3, 0, '', ('208.80.155.68', 0)), (10, 1, 6, '', ('2620:0:861:202:208:80:155:68', 0, 0, 0)), (10, 2, 17, '', ('2620:0:861:202:208:80:155:68', 0, 0, 0)), (10, 3, 0, '', ('2620:0:861:202:208:80:155:68', 0, 0, 0))]

which makes me think there is an issue with AAAA records handling.

Comment: Perhaps an issue in his install. Works as expected from both my laptop and my server.

Comment: Which OS and version?

Comment: @KlausD. The OS is Gentoo 2.2.